# Leaflet: bootstrap slider dynamically on the map

Tags: javascript, leaflet, bootstrap-slider

I added a **bootstrap slider** to my map like:
[bootstrap-slider](https://seiyria.com/bootstrap-slider/#example-6). adding to my code then:

```
var rad =0;   
var slider = new Slider("#ex6");
slider.on("slide", function(sliderValue) {
document.getElementById("ex6SliderVal").textContent = sliderValue;
rad = sliderValue;
});
```

**rad** it is the variable that I would like to pass to the radius of the circleMarker, therefore I would need that through the **slider** I can **dynamically** enlarge and decrease the radius of the markers on the map.
in the **pointToLayer function** I added:

```
  layer: {
     pointToLayer : function(featureData, latlng){

             ................       
             ................

                 if (!result.radius){                    
                    result.radius =rad;                                                                                       
                 }
                return new L.CircleMarker(latlng, result);
           }
        },
```

But I can only get the radius value of the marker not dynamically!
How can I proceed?
Thanks!

I also tried to simplify everything with:

```
pointToLayer : function(featureData, latlng){


            var result = L.circleMarker(latlng, {radius: rad});
                         return result;
          },
```

but even here the value in **rad** does not pass dynamically increasing or decreasing my slider.
I also tried to insert simplified conditions such as:

```
pointToLayer : function(featureData, latlng){


                                if (rad <= "10"){
                                var result = L.circleMarker(latlng, {radius: 10});
                                return result;
                            }
                                if (rad > "10"){
                                var result = L.circleMarker(latlng, {radius: 20});
                                return result;
                            }


              },
```

here too the value is accepted before adding GeoJSON files, if the markers are already present they do not change as the slider changes!
I also tried with an **onEachFeature: function** but maybe I left something out! where is that i'm wrong?

Comment: You seem to have missed the [`setRadius()` method](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#circlemarker-setradius) of `CircleMarker` instances.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but still I can't get the choice of the beam dynamically !